# Codeigniter order_by with CONVERT

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-order-by

I have to order a selection by `` CONVERT(`codExtern`, SIGNED) `` with codeIgniter.
If I use it like this:

```
$this->db->order_by(" CONVERT(`codExtern`, SIGNED) ");
```

the codeigniter puts the `SIGNED` word between `` ` ``-s, like:

```
CONVERT(codExtern, `INTEGER` )
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't disable identifier protection with parameters [like in the `select()` method](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L75). CI will call [CI_DB_driver::_protect_identifiers](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_driver.php#L1246) on the input [if it has a `,` in it](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L833).

Currently you can workaround this if you set the supposedly "private" property [`$_protect_identifiers`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_driver.php#L65) to `false` on your `$this->db` before calling the `order_by` method so when it runs it will skip this, and then flip it back (it helps with problematic column/table names for example). This is probably not a really good idea, in future CI versions this property might became really `private` and your code will break.

Unfortunately the database library cannot be extended, but if you are not afraid of modifying the files under `system` you can create an exception in the `order_by()` method just like the "order by random()" [got one.](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L822)

Comment: thanks for the advice, fortunately my case was not a complex one and I decided to do it with inline sql query, not building it up with `$this->db->...` methods. Thanks anyway, it seems it would be the solution for the moment.